# Dynamical allocation of array of objects using parameterized constructor C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem when dynamically allocating an array of objects.
I have created a simple class named Rectangle

```
#include <iostream>
class Rectangle
{
public:
    // parameterized constructor, providing the height and width of a rectangle
    Rectangle(int height, int width) : m_height(height), m_width(width)
    {
        std::cout << "Create a new rectangle with parameter constructor \n";
    }
    ~Rectangle()
    {
        std::cout << "delete object \n";
    }
    // calculate the area of the rectangle
    double area() const
    {
        return m_height*m_width;
    }
    // print the information of the rectangle
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Rectangle &rec)
    {
        out << "Rectangle " << rec.m_height << " x " << rec.m_width << " has area " << rec.area();
        return out;
    }

private:
    double m_height;
    double m_width;
};
```

Then in the main function, I define an array of 3 objects of the Rectangle class and given the height and width for each object.

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle * rec1 = new Rectangle[3]{{ 10, 20 }, { 20, 30 }, { 40, 50 }};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << rec1[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

However, I got an error (from VS2013) as
Error   1   error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

But if I comment the destructor in the definition of the class

```
/*~Rectangle()
{
    std::cout << "delete object \n";
}*/
```

The program can run, and I got the result as follows.

```
Create a new rectangle with parameter constructor
Create a new rectangle with parameter constructor
Create a new rectangle with parameter constructor
Rectangle 10 x 20 has area 200
Rectangle 20 x 30 has area 600
Rectangle 40 x 50 has area 2000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't know what is the problem here. Normally, we should declare a destructor in the class for some purposes. But in this case, it produces an error. I try to search the problem on the internet but I failed to find out the answer.

Comment: I suggest you have a quick look at a calendar and upgrade to VS 2017.

Comment: "Normally, we should declare a destructor" - actually, see the [Rule Of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero). Learn to use `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::vector`, and you'll essentially never need the `new` or `delete` keywords and rarely need destructors other than `virtual ~C() = default;`.

Comment: Unrelated, but your constructor is not saving the provided width and height in the private variables.

Answer (score 5):

If you get an internal compiler error, it means your compiler is broken. Either upgrade or use a different compiler. Subtle code changes can suppress the error, but it's not your code that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have test on some other compiler and it works right now.